# self invoking anonymous functions overwriting each other

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am using self invoking anonymous functions to create objects and instances at the same time. The last created object overwrites property of first object. Why is that?

```
<script>
    LF = '<br/>'; //line feed

    // object a with property name
    !function () {
        window.a = this; // make global object

        this.name = 'a';

        document.write('inside: a.name=' + this.name + LF);
    }();


    // object b with property name
    !function () {
        window.b = this; // make global object

        this.name = 'b';

        document.write('inside: b.name=' + this.name + LF);
    }();


    document.write('outisde: ' + ' a.name=' + a.name + ' b.name=' + b.name + LF);

</script>
```

results:

```
inside: a.name=a 
inside: b.name=b 
outisde: a.name=b b.name=b
```

Comment: in addition to the answers. you could change your code this way to get it work:  `new function() { window.a= this; ... }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because in your case `window === this` and `window === a` and `window === b`.
Read more here: http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/

Answer (score 3):

Inside both of your functions, `this` is `window`.  So `this.name` references the *same* variable inisde *both* functions.